# r indexing within ifelse or apply

Tags: r

searching many places, i can't find any indication as to how one can leverage the index of items when using ifelse or apply.
for a simple example, if i want to divide values in a vector by their index i can do it in a for-loop:

```
for( i in 1:length(vector) ){ vector[i] = vector[i] / i }
```

is there some internal variable that can be leveraged in an ifelse or apply statement?
e.g.: `vector = ifelse( is.finite(vector), vector/internal.index.variable, vector )` on vectors and matrices?

thanks,
tom

Comment: Just a suggestion: try to write your code so it works even when stuff is sorted differently. That would not work if you reordered your vector. You might want to not divide by the index but by another vector that just happens to be the index. That way if you reordered (then both vectors), the result would still be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`seq_along(x)` is your friend; it creates an integer vector equal to `1:length(x)`:

```
vec <- vec2 <-  c(5, Inf, 7) # Need two copies to modify one in the loop


# Your for loop example
for ( i in 1:length(vec) ) {
    vec2[i] <- vec2[i] / i
}

vec2
# [1] 5.000000      Inf 2.333333

# Accomplish the same thing with apply()
sapply(vec, '/', seq_along(vec))
# [1] 5.000000      Inf 2.333333

# Accomplish the same thing with ifelse()
ifelse(is.finite(vec), vec / seq_along(vec), vec)
# [1] 5.000000      Inf 2.333333
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks! That seems just what i've been looking for.

Comment: @tom Glad it worked out for you! If it solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
a <- c(1,2,Inf)
a / seq_along(a)
```

Infinity devided by an index is still infinity. Hence, infinite elements stay the same anyway.